# How to check whether the ListView is empty or not using custom list adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, baseadapter

I have used two adpaters in my app, one for offline mode which fetches the data from a local sqlite DB.The second adapter fetches data from server and displays the items in the listview which is common for both the adapters. In there is no data in the list I have used the empty view to show the list is empty. But even if there is data in the sqlite still it shows me the list empty. I would like to know is there any way to check whether the adapter is null or not. If it is not null it means that it should display the values in the list.

Offline adapter:

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ImagelistItems> imageList;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImagelistItems> list) {

        this.context = context;
        imageList = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return imageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImagelistItems imagelistItems = imageList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelist_items, null);

        }
        byte[] outImage = imagelistItems.getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        final Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        final TextView merchname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lsmerchantname);
        merchname.setText(imagelistItems.getMerchantname());
        final TextView paid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lspaiddate);
        paid.setText(imagelistItems.getPaidon());
        TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lsstatus);
        status.setText(imagelistItems.getStatus());
        final TextView amt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lsamount);
        amt.setText(imagelistItems.getAmount());
        ImageButton oofbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnofflinebutton);
        oofbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final TextView category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lscategory);
        category.setText(imagelistItems.getCategory());
        final TextView paymode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lspaidwith);
        paymode.setText(imagelistItems.getPaymmode());
        final TextView comment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lscomment);
        comment.setText(imagelistItems.getComment());
        final TextView moneydet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moneydetails);
        final String moen;
        CurrenctSession currenctSession = new CurrenctSession(context);
        if (currenctSession.isLoggedIn()) {
            HashMap<String, String> cur = currenctSession.getUserDetails();
            moen = cur.get(currenctSession.KEY_CURRENCY);
            moneydet.setText(moen);
        } else {
            moneydet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String am = amt.getText().toString();
                if (am.contains("km") | am.contains("m")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, MapsDetailPage.class);
                    i.putExtra("distance", amt.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("origin", merchname.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("dest", paymode.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("catg", category.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("pdate", paid.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("comm", comment.getText().toString());
                    context.startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, DetailsPage.class);
                    i.putExtra("bitmap", theImage);
                    i.putExtra("amount", amt.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("mername", merchname.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("paidon", paid.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("catg", category.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("paym", paymode.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("comm", comment.getText().toString());
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Online Adapter:

```
public class CustomlistJsonadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ReceiptMov> movieItems;


    public CustomlistJsonadapter(Activity activity, List<ReceiptMov> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onlineimagelist_items, null);

        final TextView merchantname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olsmerchantname);
        final TextView paiddate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olspaiddate);
        final TextView amounts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olsamount);
        final TextView paidwith = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olspaidwith);
        final TextView categ = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olscategory);
        final TextView comment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olscomment);
        final TextView stast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.olsstatus);

        ImageView imgview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.oimgview);
        ReceiptMov m = movieItems.get(position);


        // Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        byte[] s = m.getMimage();
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s);
        final Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        // Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(s, 0 ,s.length);

        imgview.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        merchantname.setText(m.getMerchantname());
        paiddate.setText("Paid on:" + m.getMerdate());
        amounts.setText(m.getMeramount());
        paidwith.setText(m.getMerpaid());
        categ.setText(m.getMercategory());
        comment.setText(m.getMecomment());
        stast.setText("Status: " + "Uploaded");
        final TextView moneydet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.omoneydetails);
        final String moen;
        CurrenctSession currenctSession = new CurrenctSession(activity);
        if (currenctSession.isLoggedIn()) {
            HashMap<String, String> cur = currenctSession.getUserDetails();
            moen = cur.get(currenctSession.KEY_CURRENCY);
            moneydet.setText(moen);
        } else {
            moneydet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String am = amounts.getText().toString();
                if (am.contains("km") | am.contains("m")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, MapsDetailPage.class);
                    i.putExtra("distance", amounts.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("origin", merchantname.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("dest", paidwith.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("catg", categ.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("pdate", paiddate.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("comm", comment.getText().toString());
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, DetailsPage.class);
                    i.putExtra("bitmap", theImage);
                    i.putExtra("amount", amounts.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("mername", merchantname.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("paidon", paiddate.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("catg", categ.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("paym", paidwith.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("comm", comment.getText().toString());
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

List:

```
if(imageListAdapter!=null){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        //  List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
        ArrayList<ImagelistItems> list = new ArrayList<ImagelistItems>();
        list = db.getAllLabels();
        imageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(
                ListMode.this, list);
        if (loginSession.isLoggedIn()) {
            loginSession.checkLogin();
            listView.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);
           // listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), db.getSyncStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(ListMode.this, LoginPAge.class);
            startActivity(i);
            ListMode.this.finish();
        }

    }else{
        listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    }
```

Comment: add imageListAdapter.notifydatasetChanged() after this line listView.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);

Comment: i have added but still it shows me the list empty view

Comment: Are you sure your imageListAdapter isn't null?

Comment: yes it is not null

Answer (score 3):

```
if (adapter!=null) {
    if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
        // listView not empty
    } else {
        // listView  empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getcount()` to know the number of items

```
if(adapter.getCount()>0)
{
//some rows of listview
}
else
{
//listview is empty
}
```

Hope it helps thanks

Comment: It gives me the following error:   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int nidhinkumar.reccs.ImageListAdapter.getCount()' on a null object reference
            at nidhinkumar.reccs.ListMode.onCreate(ListMode.java:197)

Comment: @rick use this after adapter object is created

Comment: sorry i didn't get you can u explain it a bit more

Comment: no it didn't works   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: @nick please post then only i can describe more

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `emptyView` before setting the `adapter` on listview.
No need to check whether the adapter is empty, listview will take care of it.

You code should look like this :

```
TextView empty = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
listView.setEmptyView(empty);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Where should I place the textView in Xml ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {

} else {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO Data Available..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(mAdapter.getItemCount()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(UpdatePorder.this, "list is filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
               Toast.makeText(UpdatePorder.this, "List is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, may help you**

```
    ImageListAdapter imageListAdapter= new ImageListAdapter();
    listviewObject.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);

    if (imageListAdapter!= null)
        if (imageListAdapter.getCount() > 0){
            // implement your work
        }else {
            // do whatever you want on empty list adapter 
        }
```